# How to count rows with Knex which are containing the same ID avoiding Knex complains about the groupBy elements are not included

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

In my App backend with Knex using PSQL I'm trying to get the count of the rows where they have the same ID.
The issue is that whatever I'm doing always the count is 1 when in reality I have 2 rows for the same ID.

My table looks

[image: [![Table message][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7sxn.png]

In the table shared I need to count the rows with the same `conversation_id` which is `1`.
The expected result should be `count = 2`

What I tried with Knex:

```
tx(tableName).select(columns.conversationId)
          .whereIn(columns.conversationId, conversationIds)
          .groupBy(columns.conversationId, columns.createdAt, columns.id);
```

The `groupBy` section if I try to remove `columns.createdAt, columns.id` it is complaining saying that those need to be included in the `groupBy` or in an aggregate function.

Removing in the following SQL those extra `groupBy` element I'm getting the right result but Knex doesn't like it and I'm stuck on it.

SQL generated as follow:

```
select
    conversation_id ,
    COUNT(*)
from
    message
group by
    conversation_id,
    created_at ,
    id ;
```

The result of this SQL is as follow

[image: Query result]

As you see the result is not good and I'm not able to make it work correctly with Knex which complain if I remove the elements from the `groupBy`

Answer (score 0):

Tinkering with some expressions in the [QueryLab](https://michaelavila.com/knex-querylab/?query=NYOwpgHgFA5ALgQwEYBswDkEFswwJQBQABCaWQHQDOYaAxnLLQPYoCuWIl5zIAbmACdKCOAEsmIAJIATfMTILyAdwAWgsJJCMW7Ttwn8hI8VNkAaIgG0YPQ8LESZlGAF1CCxc1YgGeIA), I wonder if something like the following will work:

```
tx(tableName)
      .select(columns.conversationId)
      .whereIn(columns.conversationId, conversationIds)
      .count()
```

Which would give something like (these values are placeholders, obviously):

```
select "columns"."conversationId", count(*) from "tableName" where "columns"."conversationId" in (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Already tried and not working complains about group by and still same count issue not giving me 2 as result.

Comment: The problem is using sql in the client works using Knex no going that must use in group by and using group by gives a different result. Seems a catch 22